# Difference between Ubuntu desktop and Ubuntu desktop for developers

Tags: 14.04, 15.04

So there is this variant of Ubuntu on their homepage: http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/developers

Could anyone tell me what exactly does this version include that the regular one does not?

I imagine that it must have some tools included with it but I can not find any list of tools on the page I linked above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you click on download Ubuntu on the link you will see the normal download for Ubuntu. That means there is no difference, it is just saying that Ubuntu is good for developers too, no difference. :)

Comment: Ubuntu is also the server version as well but just with a GUI, it comes with all the software packages as the server version just no desktop environment just terminal.

Comment: Thanks! Still seems a bit misleading to me. They could just say it in the regular Ubuntu download link. At least now I know.

Comment: It is more show casing the features but yeah a little weird.